# problems with reading a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to write a basic function that prints the contents from a textfile. The code I used is:

```
def open_my_file(input_file):
    in_file = open(input_file, "r")
    contents = in_file.read()
    file.close()

    word_list = contents.split(',')
    print(word_list)
```

when I try running the program, it says syntax error.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: WHERE does it report a syntax error?

Comment: Quoting the error would certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

You use `in_file` when you open & read, but `file` when you close.  That wouldn't be a syntax error, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you're opening the file you're declaring the file with the name `in_file`, when you close the file you're saying `file.close()`, because you haven't declared any variable with the name `file` the python program gives you an SyntaxError.

Change `file.close()` to `in_file.close()`